How to tell if CloseSpider was raised at the level of CrawlerProcess
I need to run my scrapers in a loop but if certain errors occur in a spider I'd like to be able to raise CloseSpiderand for this to filter up to the looping function and stop the loop.
Here's my code so far which works fine with a fully functioning spider but I've created a little MRE to test the CloseSpider use case.
from __future__ import print_function

import multiprocessing as mp
import traceback
from time import sleep
from typing import Type

from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider


class MyTestSpider(Spider):
    name = "my_test_spider"

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        raise CloseSpider


class Process(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, target: callable, *args, **kwargs):
        mp.Process.__init__(self, target=target, *args, **kwargs)

        self._pconn, self._cconn = mp.Pipe()
        self._exception = None

    def run(self):
        try:
            mp.Process.run(self)

            self._cconn.send(None)

        except Exception as e:
            tb = traceback.format_exc()

            self._cconn.send(tb)

    @property
    def exception(self):
        if self._pconn.poll():
            self._exception = self._pconn.recv()

        return self._exception


def run_crawler_loop(
    spider: Type[Spider],
    loop_wait_secs: int,
    **kwargs,
) -> None:
    while True:
        run_crawler_reactor_safe(spider=spider, **kwargs)

        sleep(loop_wait_secs)


def run_crawler_reactor_safe(spider: Type[Spider], **kwargs) -> None:
    process = Process(target=run_crawler, kwargs={"spider": spider} | kwargs)

    process.start()
    process.join()

    if process.exception:
        error, traceback = process.exception

        # send an email here

        raise error # close the loop


def run_crawler(spider: Type[Spider], **kwargs) -> None:
    process = CrawlerProcess()

    crawler = process.create_crawler(spider)

    process.crawl(crawler_or_spidercls=crawler, **kwargs)

    process.start()

    # how would I tell here if the spider was closed due to raising a CloseSpider exception?
    # I'd like to raise that exception here so I can stop the loop by raising an error in run_crawler_reactor_safe


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_crawler_loop(spider=MyTestSpider, loop_wait_secs=0)

Running this generates two log entries in twisted:
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2024-10-09 09:39:01 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myusername/opt/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 265, in crawl
    return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/myusername/opt/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 269, in _crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/myusername/opt/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 2260, in unwindGenerator
    return _cancellableInlineCallbacks(gen)
  File "/Users/myusername/opt/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 2172, in _cancellableInlineCallbacks
    _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, status, _copy_context())
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/Users/myusername/opt/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 2003, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = context.run(gen.send, result)
  File "/Users/myusername/opt/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 155, in crawl
    self.spider = self._create_spider(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/myusername/opt/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 169, in _create_spider
    return self.spidercls.from_crawler(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/myusername/opt/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 62, in from_crawler
    spider = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/myusername/GitHub/polgara_v2/so__capture_SpiderClose.py", line 17, in __init__
    raise CloseSpider
scrapy.exceptions.CloseSpider: 

2024-10-09 09:39:01 [twisted] CRITICAL: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myusername/opt/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 2003, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = context.run(gen.send, result)
  File "/Users/myusername/opt/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 155, in crawl
    self.spider = self._create_spider(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/myusername/opt/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 169, in _create_spider
    return self.spidercls.from_crawler(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/myusername/opt/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 62, in from_crawler
    spider = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/myusername/GitHub/polgara_v2/so__capture_SpiderClose.py", line 17, in __init__
    raise CloseSpider
scrapy.exceptions.CloseSpider

However, these errors seem to be handled here and are not actually raised again in any way that can be captured further up. I've looked through both the crawler and process instances when process.start() finishes in run_crawler() but I can't find any sign of the spider let alone an error message.
I've also tried looking through the twisted package and a post on SO (Stopping Twisted from swallowing exceptions) but got lost quickly...
Any ideas on how I might accomplish what I'm looking to do?

It only makes sense to raise specifically CloseSpider in places where it will be handled by Scrapy.  In your case, as you can see, it's unhandled and so you can use any other exception instead. Though you seem to call an unhandled exception "handled here" which is confusing.

Hi. Picking up your sentence on "handled here" first - I used this expression as it looks to me like twisted does handle the error and then re-raises it at the end. However, re-raising the error doesn't seem to do anything in relation to the CrawlerProcess object such that I can check for an error. Raising any other exception is also 'handled' by twisted and again doesn't seem to do anything in relation to the CrawlerProcess object. Even if it did at the level I have it (in __init__) then any other error would be handled by scrapy if it was raised in e.g. a callback...

...I'd need some mechanism to close the scraper to then get out to the run_crawler function to then check if there was an error.

I've clarified some of the language around "handled here"

No, Twisted doesn't "handle the error and then re-raises it at the end", it found an unhandled exception in a garbage-collected Deferred and printed it. But my point was that this exception is also not handled by Scrapy so you could use any other one (and IMO should, to reduce potential confusion from thinking that CloseSpider somehow closes the spider here).

Really sorry but not sure I follow. As mentioned in my previous post I've tried replacing CloseSpiderwith ValueError and though this exits the spider (as with CloseSpider) this still doesn't trigger any kind of error in the CrawlerProcess instance or even log it in any way?

Not sure what are you trying to say, sorry. Unhandled exceptions are not supposed to trigger something in CrawlerProcess or whatever. Don't use them.

Ok I've worked out a solution. It did require putting the CloseSpider into a callback but this is more realistic for IRL. I've annotated all the changes I made from the original script:
from __future__ import print_function

import multiprocessing as mp
import traceback
from time import sleep
from typing import Type

from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
from scrapy.settings import Settings


class MyTestSpider(Spider):
    name = "my_test_spider"

    start_urls = ["https://www.flashscore.co.uk/tennis/"]

    # added in a setting to enable me to record if CloseSpider was triggered
    @classmethod
    def update_settings(cls, settings: Settings):
        settings.set(
            name="CLOSESPIDER_TRIGGERED",
            value=False,
            priority="spider",
        )

        super().update_settings(settings)

    # CloseSpider records a reason of "cancelled" when triggered
    def closed(self, reason: str) -> None:
        if reason == "cancelled":
            # need to unfreeze the settings as the object is usually immutable
            self.crawler.settings.frozen = False
            self.crawler.settings.set(
                name="CLOSESPIDER_TRIGGERED",
                value=True,
                priority="spider",
            )
            self.crawler.settings.frozen = True
        
        return
    
    def parse(self, response):
        raise CloseSpider


class Process(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, target: callable, *args, **kwargs):
        mp.Process.__init__(self, target=target, *args, **kwargs)

        self._pconn, self._cconn = mp.Pipe()
        self._exception = None

    def run(self):
        try:
            mp.Process.run(self)

            self._cconn.send(None)

        except Exception as e:
            tb = traceback.format_exc()

            # amended this to send both error and traceback
            self._cconn.send((e, tb))

    @property
    def exception(self):
        if self._pconn.poll():
            self._exception = self._pconn.recv()

        return self._exception


def run_crawler_loop(
    spider: Type[Spider],
    loop_wait_secs: int,
    **kwargs,
) -> None:
    while True:
        run_crawler_reactor_safe(spider=spider, **kwargs)

        sleep(loop_wait_secs)


def run_crawler_reactor_safe(spider: Type[Spider], **kwargs) -> None:
    process = Process(target=run_crawler, kwargs={"spider": spider} | kwargs)

    process.start()
    process.join()

    if process.exception:
        error, traceback = process.exception

        # send an email here

        raise error # close the loop by re-raising the exception


def run_crawler(spider: Type[Spider], **kwargs) -> None:
    process = CrawlerProcess()

    crawler = process.create_crawler(spider)

    process.crawl(crawler_or_spidercls=crawler, **kwargs)
    process.start()

    # check if CloseSpider was triggered - if it was then raise an exception
    if crawler.settings.getbool("CLOSESPIDER_TRIGGERED"):
        raise CloseSpider


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_crawler_loop(spider=MyTestSpider, loop_wait_secs=0)

